# $HOME for new terminal tabs in a window opened in Files

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, home-directory, 21.04

I am using 21.04. After upgrading from 20.10, I notice the following:

If I open Files, then open a (Gnome) Terminal window using 'Open in Terminal', and then open a new tab in that window with SHIFT+CTRL+T my $HOME is not set. This causes problems with, e.g., Git finding .gitconfig. In such a tab, `echo $HOME` returns a blank. In any other terminal window and tab, I get my home directory as expected.

Why does this happen? How do I fix it?

I realise that the following is relevant:

When I open the tab, the following message is shown:

'To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo ".
See "man sudo_root" for details.'

And, there is no '~' before the prompt in such a tab.

Comment: Have you configured Terminal to launch a login shell?

Comment: Does your `~/.bashrc` (which usually sets `$HOME`) have errors?

Comment: @glenn-jackman I hadn't. When I did, that fixed the problem.

Comment: @waltinator Not as far as I know.

Comment: @waltinator, HOME is not set in your dotfiles: https://superuser.com/questions/271925/where-is-the-home-environment-variable-set

Comment: @glennjackman I'm now wondering whether I should just change that setting. Presumably there's a good reason why a non-login shell is the default? I'm also confused about why this changed when I upgraded.

Comment: A login shell has to process a few more rc files, so it takes a few extra milliseconds to launch. I suggest you read [6.2 Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files) and figure out where your HOME variable is getting unset.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. Also updated from 20.10 to 21.04.

Comment: @glennjackman I did some reading. Nothing in .bashrc seems to set $HOME. For login shells, I have a .profile also doesn't seem to set $HOME, but calls .bashrc. (I don't think I wrote any of these myself.)

Comment: You have to start with /etc/profile and /etc/bash.bashrc, and also anything those scripts source

Comment: @glennjackman That taught me something: the message about using sudo (mentioned in my edit to the question) comes from /etc/bash.bashrc.